# Case Sensitivity Issue with SCOM Management Pack Import via PowerShell

Tags: scom, management-pack

I am a SCOM newbie and I am facing an issue with importing a Management Pack (MP) into SCOM via PowerShell and would greatly appreciate any advice or solutions you might have.

**Environment:**

SCOM Version: 2022, Console version 10.22.10118.0
PowerShell Version: 5.1.20348
Operating System: Windows
File System: NTFS

**Problem Description:**
The Management Pack file is named `MYCOMPANY.Notepad.exe.Process.Monitor.xml` and contains XML identifiers that match this case pattern. When I attempt to import this Management Pack using the PowerShell `Import-SCManagementPack` cmdlet, the import fails with an ArgumentException.

However, I have another file named `MYCOMPANY.notepad.exe.Process.Monitor.xml` (notepad.exe lowercase) with adjusted identifiers within the XML content to have notepad.exe lowercase as well, the import succeeds.

**Error Message:**

```
> Import-SCManagementPack -ManagementPack C:\SCOM\test-pack\MYCOMPANY.Notepad.exe.Process.Monitor.xml

Import-SCManagementPack : The requested management pack is not valid. See inner exception for details.
Parameter name: managementPack
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-SCManagementPack -ManagementPack C:\SCOM\test-pack\MYCOM ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (:) [Import-SCManagementPack], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Failed to import management pack named MYCOMPANY.Notepad.exe.Process.Monitor,Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Core.Cmdlets.ImportSCSMManagementPackCommand
```

Attached is the PowerShell script excerpt and the XML snippets I was trying to import:
https://gist.github.com/dm-oryx/91594276c096b09db4897b08744dce45.

**Specific Questions:**

- Is the Import-SCManagementPack cmdlet known to have issues with case sensitivity for file names or XML content identifiers?
- Are there any settings in SCOM that might impact how file names are interpreted, particularly for PowerShell operations?
- Has anyone else encountered similar behavior or found a workaround that allows the use of mixed-case names for Management Pack files and identifiers?

Thank you for your assistance and insights!

I tried to import Management Pack XML using Import-SCManagementPack and it worked for process named notepad.exe, but not for Notepad.exe